# Manual Certificate Validation

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have an ASP.net Webservice (asmx) which returns some secure stuff from my application. I want to create a client application which uses a certificate to connect to this service and calls this method. Using a certificate I want to ensure only this special client application can call this webservice method.

I've read hundreds of complicated articles how to setup the infrastructure but I quited because of annoying setups and very complicated parts (i.E. certificate store setups,...). I decided to manually do the certificate validation within my service method. This way I know what's going on and I don't have to rely on complicated server setups.

But the question is: How can I do that?

This stubs represent what I want to do:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetSecureData() {
    if(!ValidateClientCertificate()) {
        throw new HttpException((int) (HttpStatusCode.BadRequest), "Bad Request");
    }
    return "i am secure";
}

private bool ValidateClientCertificate() {
    HttpClientCertificate cert = HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate;
    if (!cert.IsPresent || !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection) {
        return false;
    }

    bool isValid = /* is cert the almighty client certificate? */
    return isValid;
}
```

On client side I do something like this:

```
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\secure.cer");
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new CertPolicy();
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myserver/Secure.asmx/GetSecureData");
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
Request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

It would be awesome if I can put some sort of "public key" into the application (App_Data) and check if the client certificate received is the one represented by this public key.

The problems are:

1. How do I do the magic shown as comment in the first code piece?
2. I guess the IIS and ASP.net will block the unknown/unverified client certificate. I would need to disable this check for this special service method.

Please don't blame me if the answer is easy and already answered thousands of times. There are thousands of articles about this topic with 100 different solutions and variants. I couldn't find the matching one for my problem.

Comment: Were you aware that ASMX is a legacy technology that should not be used for new development? WCF should be used instead if you have a choice.

Comment: @john: For sure we considered WCF, but it seems creating a WCF solution is more complicated and unmaintainable for our needs. It has a way higher time and money effort to maintain all the certificate stuff across our development machines and development- and productive-installations. For the future we may switch to WCF but for now we cannot effort the time and money setting up the development and deployment infrastructure. We only have a single service method which needs to be secured. A manual check would be as secure as a complex infrastructure.

Comment: Wow! I can't imagine why you think WCF is more complicated! Are you using .NET 4.0 yet? The configuration got _much_ simpler, as in: sometimes no configuration at all.

Comment: Sorry but are you reading my posts? It's not about the WCF part which is complicated. The WCF service is implemented within seconds but creating a certificate client authentication and authorization on top of this the painful task. And that's what my question is about. You cannot simply put your certificate files into your application and tell the system to perform only allow this client certificate to call the service. You have to setup the certificate store, IIS, the ASP.net configuration. Doing this on all development  machines and application servers is a too expensive task.

Comment: Ahah, thanks, no chance to automate it?

Comment: Of course there is a chance. But it's a too expensive task we cannot effort now. Using this custom ssl certificate check I mentioned we could distribute the certificates with the solution and the application and validate against it. For now we made an RSA encrypted password to check if the client is authorized. So we can put the public key onto the server and the private key to the client.